# syntax error near unexpected token in makefile

Tags: python, bash, makefile, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a template in Makefile to reuse Python virtualenv.
in Makefile I define:

`ENV_CREATE ?= $(shell python3 -m virtualenv venv)`
and in target:

```
set_up:
    $(ENV_CREATE) ; \
    . venv/bin/activate
```

As a result of Makefiule target execution I'm getting

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo created virtual environment CPython3.7.9.final.0-64 in 333ms   creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/marian/Work/git/sigma/sphere/sphere-data-platform/venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/marian/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)     added seed packages: pip==21.1.2, setuptools==57.0.0, wheel==0.36.2   activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator ; . venv/bin/activate    python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements-dev.txt ; '
make: *** [setup] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `$(info ENV_CREATE=[$(ENV_CREATE)])` to check the value of `ENV_CREATE` immediately after it's been set.  Does it look correct?

Comment: yes it does
`ENV_CREATE=[created virtual environment CPython3.7.9.final.0-64 in 300ms   creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/marian/Work/git/sigma/sphere/sphere-data-platform/venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/marian/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)     added seed packages: pip==21.1.2, setuptools==57.0.0, wheel==0.36.2   activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator]`

Comment: That text isn't a valid command (or command) that can be passed to the shell which is what you are trying to do.  What is the purpose of the `$(ENV_CREATE)` statement in the command section of the `set_up` rule?

Comment: I'm trying to create and activate Python virtual env using variable, so I can re-use it in other targets to avoid code duplication
like: `CREATE_ENV = $(shell python3 ...)`. and then later in other target:
`$(CREATE_ENV) ; \ install_requirements`

Answer (score 2):

In `ENV_CREATE ?= $(shell...)` the right hand side seems to be evaluated non-recursively (that is, immediately). So the `ENV_CREATE` variable is assigned the result of this shell script: `[created ...`.

In your recipe you use the expansion of this make variable (`$(ENV_CREATE)`) as shell syntax, while it is not shell syntax, it is the output message of `python3 -m virtualenv venv`.

There is absolutely no point in using the `shell` make function in a recipe which is already... a shell script. Try:

```
ENV_CREATE ?= python3 -m virtualenv venv

set_up:
    $(ENV_CREATE) ; \
    . venv/bin/activate
```

Make will expand the recipe before passing it to the shell. So what will be passed to the shell is:

```
python3 -m virtualenv venv ; . venv/bin/activate
```

But note that sourcing (`. venv/bin/activate`) as the last command of a recipe will probably not do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use another target?

```
venv:
      python3 -m virtualenv venv


set_up: venv
        . venv/bin/activate
```

This way, you only create the virtual environment if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the best way. Seems like i don't need a `$(shell python 3...)` construction.
I have defined variable with Make commands(no shell) and injected it as one-liner:

```
ENV_CREATE := python3 -m virtualenv venv ; . venv/bin/activate ;

setup:
$(ENV_CREATE) python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

now I can re-use `$(ENV_CREATE)` in other targets the same way(integration tests, unit tests, etc.)